# How to restart a python script after x amount of time?

Tags: python, shell

I have a script that records audio for 15 sec, then kills itself (this needs to happen since that is the only way the recording stops using gstreamer).

Now, I want to make this script restart after 2 mins, indefinitely.

How?

I can't do it in the script itself since the process ends up being killed, and I can't figure out how to do it from the outside with another python script or bash (or shell for that matter). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code. The name is Rscript.py

```
import gi
import datetime, time
import sys
import signal  
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

autoaudiosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "audioconvert")
vorbisenc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("vorbisenc", "vorbisenc")
oggmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("oggmux", "oggmux")
filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")
url = datetime.datetime.now()
filesink.set_property("location",url)
pipeline.add( autoaudiosrc)
pipeline.add( audioconvert)
pipeline.add( vorbisenc)
pipeline.add( oggmux)
pipeline.add( filesink)

autoaudiosrc.link( audioconvert)
audioconvert.link( vorbisenc)
vorbisenc.link( oggmux)
oggmux.link( filesink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
signal.alarm(15)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of the script? It's not clear why you need to kill the script ref. gstreamer...

Comment: Create a script that verify if your program is running if not start it.

Comment: This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ 1 ]];do
    myapp &
    pid=$!
    sleep 120
    kill -9 $pid
done
```