# Rerun python script after 10 seconds

Tags: python, sleep

I am trying to rerun my python script every 10 seconds. I have tried various things with the time.sleep function but nothing seems to be working. I have tried different variants of time.sleep:

```
 def job()
   # script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        job()
        time.sleep(10)
```

but not finding the correct place/way to implement it. I don't want to rerun a function, but the full code.

This is the script I am trying to rerun:

```
import...

def main():
    # parse the command line arguments
    args = ConfigArgumentParser(description=__doc__).parse_args()

    if _debug: _log.debug("initialization")
    if _debug: _log.debug("    - args: %r", args)

    # make a device object
    this_device = LocalDeviceObject(
        objectName=args.ini.objectname,
        objectIdentifier=('device', int(args.ini.objectidentifier)),
        maxApduLengthAccepted=int(args.ini.maxapdulengthaccepted),
        segmentationSupported=args.ini.segmentationsupported,
        vendorIdentifier=int(args.ini.vendoridentifier),

    )

    # make a sample application
    this_application = BIPSimpleApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)

    # make some random input objects
    for i in range(1, RANDOM_OBJECT_COUNT + 1):
        ravo = RandomAnalogValueObject(
            objectIdentifier=('analogValue', i),
            objectName='Temp%d' % (i,),

        )

        this_application.add_object(ravo)

    # make sure they are all there

    _log.debug("    - object list: %r", this_device.objectList)

    _log.debug("running")

    run()

    _log.debug("fini")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please review the guidelines for posting questions and only including necessary code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also id do it with a while loop.

Comment: "I don't want to rerun a function, but the full code." Why? You want to rerun the whole thing with the imports and all ? You might want to use an external thing (bash, cron,...). Otherwise, the while loop is fine (see Divyessh answer) but you were so close I'm in doubt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart a python script after x amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266606/restart-a-python-script-after-x-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the whole thing to run (even bootstrap code), you can use a shell script to do it.

This won't refresh environment variables though.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do 
  sleep 10
  python script.py
done
```

If you need to refresh environment variables (you seem to need it because of RANDOM_OBJECTS), add `eval "$(exec /usr/bin/env -i "${SHELL}" -l -c "export")"` to the mix. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581684

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(10)
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just restart your whole script after 10s.

Applied to your code it would look like this:

```
import os
import time
import json
import sys

from bacpypes.debugging import bacpypes_debugging, ModuleLogger
from bacpypes.consolelogging import ConfigArgumentParser

from bacpypes.core import run

from bacpypes.primitivedata import Real
from bacpypes.object import AnalogValueObject, Property, register_object_type
from bacpypes.errors import ExecutionError

from bacpypes.app import BIPSimpleApplication
from bacpypes.local.device import LocalDeviceObject


# Read Json
with open('ObjectList.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


    def get_present_value(no):
        for a in data['AnalogValues']:
            if a['ObjectIdentifier'] == int(no):
                return a['PresentValue']
        return None

ai_1 = (get_present_value(1))

print(ai_1)

# some debugging
_debug = 0
_log = ModuleLogger(globals())

# settings
RANDOM_OBJECT_COUNT = int(os.getenv('RANDOM_OBJECT_COUNT', 1))


#
#   RandomValueProperty
#

class RandomValueProperty(Property):

    def __init__(self, identifier):
        if _debug: RandomValueProperty._debug("__init__ %r", identifier)
        Property.__init__(self, identifier, Real, default=0.0, optional=True, mutable=False)

    def ReadProperty(self, obj, arrayIndex=None):
        if _debug: RandomValueProperty._debug("ReadProperty %r arrayIndex=%r", obj, arrayIndex)

        # access an array
        if arrayIndex is not None:
            raise ExecutionError(errorClass='property', errorCode='propertyIsNotAnArray')

        # return a random value

        value = ai_1

        if _debug: RandomValueProperty._debug("    - value: %r", value)

        return value


    def WriteProperty(self, obj, value, arrayIndex=None, priority=None, direct=False):
        if _debug: RandomValueProperty._debug("WriteProperty %r %r arrayIndex=%r priority=%r direct=%r", obj, value,
                                              arrayIndex, priority, direct)
        raise ExecutionError(errorClass='property', errorCode='writeAccessDenied')


bacpypes_debugging(RandomValueProperty)

#
#   Random Value Object Type
#

class RandomAnalogValueObject(AnalogValueObject):
    properties = [
        RandomValueProperty('presentValue'),
    ]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if _debug: RandomAnalogValueObject._debug("__init__ %r", kwargs)
        AnalogValueObject.__init__(self, **kwargs)


bacpypes_debugging(RandomAnalogValueObject)
register_object_type(RandomAnalogValueObject)


#
#   __main__
#

def main():
    # parse the command line arguments
    args = ConfigArgumentParser(description=__doc__).parse_args()

    if _debug: _log.debug("initialization")
    if _debug: _log.debug("    - args: %r", args)

    # make a device object
    this_device = LocalDeviceObject(
        objectName=args.ini.objectname,
        objectIdentifier=('device', int(args.ini.objectidentifier)),
        maxApduLengthAccepted=int(args.ini.maxapdulengthaccepted),
        segmentationSupported=args.ini.segmentationsupported,
        vendorIdentifier=int(args.ini.vendoridentifier),

    )

    # make a sample application
    this_application = BIPSimpleApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)

    # make some random input objects
    for i in range(1, RANDOM_OBJECT_COUNT + 1):
        ravo = RandomAnalogValueObject(
            objectIdentifier=('analogValue', i),
            objectName='Temp%d' % (i,),

        )

        this_application.add_object(ravo)

    # make sure they are all there

    _log.debug("    - object list: %r", this_device.objectList)

    _log.debug("running")

    run()

    _log.debug("fini")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    time.sleep(10)
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)  # Your script restarts after 10s with this
```